# Can't identify the MySQL error in a query that I made in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
$sql = 'insert into scheduled_hikes ( organizer_member_id , hike_group_id , hike_title , hike_description , 
hike_date , end_date , dogs_allowed , mileage , feet_elevation , start_time , end_time , recommended_clothing , recommended_food , 
cancel_condition , contact_phone , show_on_home_page , park_name , full_address , lng , lat , hike_privacy)          

values ( '.$member_id.' , '.$hiking_group_id.' , "'.$hike_name.'" , "'.$hike_description.'" ,
 STR_TO_DATE( "'.$date_string.'" , "%m-%d-%Y" ) , STR_TO_DATE( "'.$date_string2.'" , "%m-%d-%Y" ) , '.$dog_radio.' , '.$mileage.' , '.$feet_elevation.' , "'.$start_time.'" ,
 "'.$end_time.'" , "'.$recommended_clothing.'" , "'.$recommended_food.'" , "'.$cancel_condition.'" , "'.$contact_phone.'", '.$show_on_home_page.' , "'.$park_name.'" ,  "'.$full_address.'" , '.$lng.' , '.$lat.' , '.$hike_privacy.' )';
```

And I get this error about it:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , 1 )' at line 8
```

I can't seem to identify anything wrong with the query. Would anyone be able to spot where the problem might be?

Here is the output of the SQL:

```
insert into scheduled_hikes ( organizer_member_id , hike_group_id , hike_title , hike_description , hike_date , end_date ,
                                                dogs_allowed , mileage , feet_elevation , start_time , end_time , recommended_clothing , recommended_food ,
                                                cancel_condition , contact_phone , show_on_home_page , park_name , full_address , lng , lat , hike_privacy)
                                                 values ( 2 , -1 , "NY Hike" ,
                                                 "Manhattan" ,
                                                 STR_TO_DATE( "05-30-2014" , "%m-%d-%Y" ) , STR_TO_DATE( "--" , "%m-%d-%Y" ) , 1 , 3 , 0 , "4:00 PM" ,
                                                 "" , "" , " " , "  " , ""
                                                 , 1 , "" ,  "Manhattan" ,  ,
                                                 , 1 )
```

Thank you!

Comment: what $variable is 1 ? print the variables and you see wich value is 1 then you know wich value is not inserting. $cancel_condition seesm the one that could be containing 1 to me.

Comment: Please post the output of `echo $sql`

Comment: Print the `$sql` after variable substitution.  That often shows the problem.  My guesses are:  (1) you have a single quote in one of the strings; (2) you have more values than columns; (3) you have unbalanced parentheses.  You don't seem to have a reserved word problem, which is the first thing to check for.

Comment: I think it's the odd mix of ' and "

Comment: `$lng` and `$lat` are empty.

Comment: Why is `$date_string2` set to `--`? That's not a valid date. You have a serious problem setting your variables.

Comment: @Barmar yes that was the issue!! If you'd like to post that as the answer I'll accept it. Thank you. This solved my bug :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the variable `$lng` and `$lat`. They're empty, so you end up with two commas in a row in the query, which is not valid.

You should also check the code that sets `$date_string2` and `$end_time`. `$date_string2` is set to `"--"`, which isn't a valid date, and `$end_time` is an empty string (I don't know if this is OK in your application). Lots of other variables are also empty, but maybe that's OK.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass php variables of string type in you query you should escape them with `'` not `"` (when you are passing variables of numeric type you don't need them at all):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO scheduled_hikes 
         ( organizer_member_id
         , hike_group_id
         , hike_title 
         , hike_description
         , hike_date
         , end_date
         , dogs_allowed
         , mileage
         , feet_elevation
         , start_time
         , end_time
         , recommended_clothing
         , recommended_food
         , cancel_condition
         , contact_phone
         , show_on_home_page
         , park_name
         , full_address
         , lng
         , lat
         , hike_privacy)
        VALUES 
         ( '".$member_id."' 
         , '".$hiking_group_id."'
         , '".$hike_name."'
         ,  '".$hike_description."'
         , STR_TO_DATE( '".$date_string."' , '%m-%d-%Y' )
         , STR_TO_DATE( '".$date_string2."' , '%m-%d-%Y' )
         , '".$dog_radio."'
         , '".$mileage."'
         , '".$feet_elevation."'
         , '".$start_time."'
         , '".$end_time."'
         , '".$recommended_clothing."'
         , '".$recommended_food."'
         , '".$cancel_condition."'
         , '".$contact_phone."'
         , '".$show_on_home_page."'
         , '".$park_name."'
         , '".$full_address."'
         , '".$lng."'
         , '".$lat."'
         , '".$hike_privacy."' )";
```

Comment: He put quotes around `$lng` and `$lat`, so you won't get a syntax error when they're empty. But you should probably fix the problem that allows them to be empty in the first place.

Comment: He's using the correct type of quotes in his query. The difference is that he doesn't have quotes around some of the variables, because they're supposed to be numbers and don't need to be quoted.

Comment: Where did he confuse the different quotes in his query?

Comment: @Barmar : Things like `"'.$hike_name.'"` instead of `\''.$member_id.'\'`.

Comment: That's the same as in your answer. There's no problem there in his original code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the mish-mash of inverted commas and quotation marks. Also, the whole 'stop-start' thing (".") is unnecessary in my view - and writing it all out on one line DOES NOT HELP. Try this instead...

```
 "
INSERT INTO scheduled_hikes 
(organizer_member_id 
,hike_group_id 
,hike_title 
,hike_description 
,hike_date 
,end_date
,dogs_allowed 
,mileage 
,feet_elevation 
,start_time 
,end_time 
,recommended_clothing 
,recommended_food 
,cancel_condition 
,contact_phone 
,show_on_home_page 
,park_name
,full_address 
,lng 
,lat 
,hike_privacy
) VALUES 
('$member_id' 
,'$hiking_group_id'
,'$hike_name'" 
,'$hike_description'
, STR_TO_DATE('$date_string','%m-%d-%Y') 
, STR_TO_DATE('$date_string2','%m-%d-%Y') 
,'$dog_radio'
,'$mileage'
,'$feet_elevation'
,'$start_time'
,'$end_time'
,'$recommended_clothing' 
,'$recommended_food' 
,'$cancel_condition' 
,'$contact_phone'
,'$show_on_home_page'
,'$park_name' 
,'$full_address'
,'$lng'
,'$lat'
,'$hike_privacy'
);
";
```

Also, it should go without saying that you should be using mysqli or PDO, and, crucially, prepared statements.

Comment: Could you explain what you changed and why?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use variables in this string if you are using double quotes(").

```
$sql = "insert into scheduled_hikes ( organizer_member_id , hike_group_id , hike_title , hike_description , hike_date , end_date , dogs_allowed , mileage , feet_elevation , start_time , end_time , recommended_clothing , recommended_food , cancel_condition , contact_phone , show_on_home_page , park_name , full_address , lng , lat , hike_privacy)

values ($member_id, $hiking_group_id, $hike_name, $hike_description,".STR_TO_DATE($date_string,"%m-%d-%Y").",".STR_TO_DATE($date_string2,"%m-%d-%Y").",$dog_radio, $mileage, $feet_elevation, $start_time, $end_time, $recommended_clothing, $recommended_food, $cancel_condition, $contact_phone, $show_on_home_page, $park_name, $full_address, $lng, $lat, $hike_privacy)";
```